# Bash script double expressions causing issue

Tags: bash, unix, double

I'm trying to write a simple script that goes checks the number of lines that contain a certain string (which contains a double). However I'm having some issues. Here is the script I've written

```
#!/bin/bash

x=0.1
while [ $x -le 5 ]
do
        cat b.txt | grep "Red: $x" | wc -l >> blah
        x=$(( $x + 0.1 ))
done
```

However, when I try to execute it I get the following error which I'm not sure how to resolve:

```
/counter: line 4: [: 0.1: integer expression expected
```

Please could someone help me out?

**Example file:**

```
Red: 0.1
Red: 1.1
Red: 2.3
Red: 0.5
Red: 3.9
Red: 1.0
Red: 4.4
```

Comment: As an aside, the Useless Use of Cat canbe replaced with simply `grep -c "Red: $x" b.txt >>blah`. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for floating-point operations, it's best to use "bc": here is a decent tutorial:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash

```
x=0.1
x=`echo $x+0.1|bc`
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash only works with integers.  See the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section in the bash manual page.

(Even if it did floating point you would get into trouble with decimal fractions.  Consider representing 0.1 with the value 1, 0.2 as 2, and so on, so that 4.7 becomes 47.  You can then grep for the tens digit followed by a literal period followed by the ones digit.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bc` to do floating-point ARITHMETIC:

```
[ $(bc<<<"$x<5") -eq 1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use awk for this type of `non-Integer Mathematical calculations`. Consider this awk script:

```
awk '/Red:/{if (sum<5) sum+=$2;} END{print sum;}' file
```